# Finding equal frequency from discrete data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, discretization

i have to find equal width from time series data.

So far,i could do it by manually selecting every single column,and then applying the condition. But i need a faster way to do it.

The time-series data:

```
Time    ulaR    trxA

0       0.6457325   0.4040438
50      0.4594477   0.4172161
100     0.4244469   0.3878299
150     0.391452    0.49735
200     0.3570379   0.4930038
250     0.3730624   0.4221448
300     0.3676819   0.3796647
350     0.3688949   0.4228213
400     0.4018654   0.439482
450     0.3934677   0.4039933
500     0.3571651   0.3264575
550     0.5451287   0.3471816
600     0.6520524   0.3710635
650     0.6776012   0.4173777
700     0.684412    0.3812378
750     0.7298819   0.3735065
800     0.739083    0.3195176
850     0.6394782   0.213515
900     0.6483277   0.3721211
950     0.7003584   0.3528451
1000    0.6926971   0.3867717
```

My Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import csv
import array as ar

infile="Ecoli-1_dream4_timeseries.tsv"
outfile="tempecoli.csv"
df=pd.read_csv(infile,delimiter="\t",dtype=float)

a1=np.array(df['ulaR'])
s=df.sort_values(['ulaR'])
s1=np.array(s['ulaR'])
gr=list()

for i in range(len(s1)):
  for j in range(len(a1)):
    if s1[i]==a1[j]:
        if j<=7:
            gr.append(0)
        elif j>7 and j<=14:
            gr.append(1)
        else:
            gr.append(2)


##########

a1=np.array(df['trxA'])
s=df.sort_values(['trxA'])
s1=np.array(s['trxA'])
gr1=list()

for i in range(len(s1)):
  for j in range(len(a1)):
     if s1[i]==a1[j]:
         if j<=7:
            gr1.append(0)
         elif j>7 and j<=14:
            gr1.append(1)
         else:
            gr1.append(2)

#############


group1=pd.Series(gr,name="ulaR")
group2=pd.Series(gr1,name="trxA")
df2=pd.concat([group1,group2],axis=1)
df2.to_csv("ecoli1.csv")
print("Completed")
```

If you run this code,you will get the result. I do not want any new result,all i want it a more time efficient code to get the desired result. Because,writing the names of each code and then applying the conditions takes a lot of time. 
A little bit of help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) on `axis=0` to get the position of the value in each column if sorted, then [`digitize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html) with the different binning conditions to get the three values 0, 1 or 2 as in your case:

```
l_col = ['ulaR', 'trxA']
bins = [-1., 7., 14., np.inf] # I use -1 as first bound to ensure 0 is in the same bin than 1 to 7
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.digitize(df[l_col].values.argsort(axis=0), bins, right=True)-1,
                       columns=l_col)
# the -1 after digitize is because it starts at 1 not 0
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Thanks,i understood the code. You were a great help.

Comment: @NetranjitBorgohain glad it works for you. sorrywhen you asked for more explanantion, I did not have time to do so!

Answer (score 0):

You're complaining that this algorithm is quadratic in timeseries length:

```
for i in range(len(s1)):
  for j in range(len(a1)):
    if s1[i]==a1[j]:
        if j<=7:
            gr.append(0)
        elif j>7 and j<=14:
            gr.append(1)
        else:
            gr.append(2)
```

## communicating with humans

From a documentation perspective there are several issues with your implementation.

1. First and foremost, you did not name the algorithm of interest. Please please `def` a function, with an informative name, and a [docstring](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/python-docstrings/), and call the function.
2. You have an expression with [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)), `7 < j <= 14`. Please give names to those numbers. That will also give you an opportunity to add a comment line for a number if the name is not quite descriptive enough. Also, there should be a comment describing the meaning of the three categories you're appending, perhaps using names like `LO`, `MED`, `HI`.
3. The inconsistency of (gr, group1) vs (gr1, group2) is, ummm, a bit jarring.

## communicating with the machine

1. Generally, when you care about speed, pushing loops out of python and into pandas / numpy is the way to go. You already accomplished this in the `.sort_values()` call. Writing English descriptions about your data properties will help you to formulate your algorithm in terms of [documented primitives](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/).
2. You sorted, and then perversely are doing N^2 equality tests to see where the sorted values wound up. Wouldn't you like to track where they went? I don't know what your algorithm does at a high level, but at a low level it looks like you're categorizing each example into one of three [quantiles](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.quantile.html). Even without using pandas explicit quantile support, you could have tacked on a sequential `index` column (or massaged the existing `Time` column, see below) so an index ordinal accompanies your data value during sorting. Then your linear scan can easily see if the current data value came from near the beginning or the end of the series. Bottom line: give the machine what it will soon need, don't strip ordinals only to reconstruct them later.

## sorted data

```
$ sort -nk2 < ecoli.tsv
200     0.3570379   0.4930038
500     0.3571651   0.3264575
300     0.3676819   0.3796647
350     0.3688949   0.4228213
250     0.3730624   0.4221448
150     0.391452    0.49735
450     0.3934677   0.4039933
400     0.4018654   0.439482
100     0.4244469   0.3878299
50      0.4594477   0.4172161
550     0.5451287   0.3471816
850     0.6394782   0.213515
0       0.6457325   0.4040438
900     0.6483277   0.3721211
600     0.6520524   0.3710635
650     0.6776012   0.4173777
700     0.684412    0.3812378
1000    0.6926971   0.3867717
950     0.7003584   0.3528451
750     0.7298819   0.3735065
800     0.739083    0.3195176
```

Comment: Can you give me a example. I am very new to python and overall programming also